# When I use footer component in react , footer does not set at the bottom of the page

Tags: reactjs

I fixed it! I had h-screen instead of min-h-screen in the home component

When I use footer component in react , footer does not set at the bottom of the page. It fits in the middle

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
        `<Navbar />
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={ <Home /> } />
                <Route path="about" element={ <About /> } />
                <Route path="collection" element={ <Collection /> }/>
                <Route path="contact" element={ <Contact /> } />
                <Route path='*' element={ <Error /> } />
            </Routes>
        <Footer />
      </>
    )
}
```

footer

```
import React from 'react'
const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Footer</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I tried almost everything but...

Comment: Please provide a code snippet of your footer conponent and the parent component.

Comment: Why do you expect it to be at the bottom? I don't see any code that aligns the footer to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap your components in a `div` and style the div using `flex-box`

```
      <div className="flex flex-col justify-between"> //if you are using tailwindCSS if not give the div a className of your choice styles are down below
        <div>
          <Navbar />
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={ <Home /> } />
                <Route path="about" element={ <About /> } />
                <Route path="collection" element={ <Collection /> }/>
                <Route path="contact" element={ <Contact /> } />
                <Route path='*' element={ <Error /> } />
            </Routes>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
```

**css**

```
 body{
    min-height: 100vh;
    height: 100%;
  }

.className{
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: col;
     justify-content: between;
  }
```

this will push down the footer to the bottom even when there is no content on the screen/routes optionally you can push the footer down even more by using the `margin` property

if you are trying to make the footer always at the bottom ie make it fixed to the bottom overlaying any content u can use the styles below on the footer and omit the code I wrote above

```
.footer_class{
    display: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 100; //optionally edit this value and make it greater than any other element that might have a greater z-index than the footer that might intersect with it
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no more code to fix but you could be just looking for it be fixed at bottom by positioning?

```
.footer-div {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 300px; /* height of your footer */
  width: 100%;
}
```